# mongoose.connection Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aws-serverless

When trying to establish a connection to the DB in atlas. I get `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')`

db.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

dotenv.config()


let connection_uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
let cachedMongoConn = null;

export const connectToDatabase = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connection
    console.log(mongoose.connect)
      .on("error", (error) => {
        console.log("Error: connection to DB failed");
        reject(error);
      })
      .on("close", () => {
        console.log("Error: Connection to DB lost");
        process.exit(1);
      })
      // Connected to DB
      .once("open", () => {
        // Display connection information
        const infos = mongoose.connections;

        infos.map((info) =>
          console.log(`Connected to ${info.host}:${info.port}/${info.name}`)
        );
        // Return successful promise
        resolve(cachedMongoConn);
      });
    if (!cachedMongoConn) {
      cachedMongoConn = mongoose.connect(connection_uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        connectTimeoutMS: 60000,
        bufferCommands: false, 
      });
    } else {
      console.log("MongoDB: using cached database instance");
      resolve(cachedMongoConn);
    }
  });
};
```

Commenting out both `.on` I get the same error on `.once`

Not sure why I'm having issues with connection with `mongoose.connection`, maybe its an ES6 issue.

Any help you provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a mistake copying or are you doing `console.log(mongoose.connect).on()` ?

Comment: Make sure that you are calling the `mongoose.connect()` function before trying to access the `mongoose.connection` object. `mongoose.connection` is created when you call `mongoose.connect()`, so calling it first will ensure that the object is defined.

Comment: wasn't a mistake...thats how it is in the actual code. Either way, It still was giving me the `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')` error

Answer (score 0):

You put the debugging

```
console.log(mongoose.connect)
```

in the wrong place. It should be

```
mongoose.connection
  .on("error", (error) => {
```

Even tho it's on a new line, `.on` still refers to `mongoose.connection`. You can't just insert a new command in between and expect it to work.

**UPDATE**:

"Invalid scheme" error is not related and is not an excuse to place `console.log` anywhere in the code. Check the backtrace of the error, it has line number where it occurs - put `console.log` there, e.g.

```
if (!cachedMongoConn) {
  console.log(connection_uri)
  cachedMongoConn = mongoose.connect(connection_uri, {
```

Connection url comes from the environment variable `MONGODB_URI` or `.env` file. The former has precedence.

Comment: Removing the console.log gives the error `Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"` I was trying to see what was being passed in the uri.